# Unable to install Expo for React Native in windows

Tags: node.js, react-native, webpack, expo

I have installed Node version 12.13.0 and Npm version 6.12.0 on my windows machine. As described in the React Native documentation when i run the command `npm install -g expo-cli` it shows error shown below.

I had uninstalled Node and reinstalled it but facing the same error.

```
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > joi > hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > joi > topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > joi > topo > hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > @expo/webpack-config > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > @expo/webpack-config > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > joi > hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > @expo/webpack-config > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > joi > topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning expo-cli > @expo/xdl > @expo/webpack-config > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > joi > topo > hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You can try to install with npm version 6.9.0 and node version 10.16.3.

Comment: Those are just warnings from expo dependencies; the install should have worked

Comment: @nikolai-serg yes, i was doing it with Node version 10.16.3 and npm version 6.9.0 before this version but was facing the same issue.

Comment: @zaytrix Nope, the installation is not working :(                                                                       This is why i am here.

Comment: Are there any other errors that it displays?